# "Don't Allow" in LocationManager keeps logging errors

Tags: iphone, locationmanager, didfailwitherror

I have an app that checked for location. It asks the user to use location and if the user says no on the menu there is an issue when i load the mapview.

Once i select the mapView it asks for the user location again. If the user says no again my console keeps displaying errors/warning as well as my NSLog from the "didFailWithError" of my location Manager class.

Is there a way of stopping the LocationManage:didFailWithErrors if the user has already said no? I don't think Apple would accept my app if the Log file gets filled up my the LocationManager

Here is an example of what gets repeated in the console

```
ERROR,Time,290362745.002,Function,"void CLClientHandleDaemonDataRegistration(__CLClient*, const CLDaemonCommToClientRegistration*, const __CFDictionary*)",server did not accept client registration 1
WARNING,Time,290362745.005,Function,"void CLClientHandleDaemonInvalidation(__CFMessagePort*, void*)",client 1035.0 has been disconnected from daemon
2010-03-15 12:19:05.002 SAQ[1035:207] LocationManager Error Denied by user
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Documentation on `-didFailWithError:` method says:

> If the user denies your application’s
>   use of the location service, this
>   method reports a kCLErrorDenied error.
>   Upon receiving such an error, you
>   should stop the location service.

So after receiving this error you should message you location manager to stop updating location:

```
[manager stopUpdatingLocation];
```

If you're using MKMapView I think setting its `showsUserLocation` property to NO should do the trick.

Comment: Indeed.... My map view was loading showUserLocation for both cases (location found of denied). Thanks, frustrating when the answer is so simple... Thanks again

Comment: Even if stopUpdatingLocation is called immediatley, I still receive always two didFailWithError calls.

Answer (score 0):

It is your responsibility to check the error code and stop updating the location if the error code is `kCLErrorDenied`.